# jQuery Mobile Page - Something wrong with structure - does not fire $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

Have this bit of involved code.  The page lists leave applications submitted by team members and allows the manager to approve or reject the application. The flow of the page is :

1. On pageshow, getLeaveDetails() is called
2. getLeaveDetails() calls /webservices/getPendingLeaveApps.ashx using $.ajax
3. On success, showForm(data, textStatus, jqXHR) is called - this works fine
4. showForm creates the markup inside a  - this works fine
5. The markup created at runtime includes buttons - this works fine
6. The two buttons "approve" and "reject" call their respective functions approveLeave(iID) and rejectLeave(iID) - of course pass the ID to approve or reject - this also works
7. The approveLeave(iID) and rejectLeave(iID), in turn use $.ajax to call an .ASHX page, pass the ID as a parameter for the ASHX to process the action - approve or reject as selected on the page - THIS is not working

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there a better structure anyone can propose?  Any assistance is very, very welcome.  Not experience at all in JS and HTML.

Thanks very much

Best wishes

Iyer

```
<div data-role="page"  id="pLeave" data-add-back-btn="true"  data-back-btn-text="Home">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pLeave').live('pageshow', function () {
        getLeaveDetails() ;
    }) ;

    function getLeaveDetails() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {numRows: 10},
            url: '/webservices/getPendingLeaveApps.ashx', 
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                showForm(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ;
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown + ' ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + jqXHR.data + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                //$("#result_labels").append('<p> textStatus ' + textStatus + '</p>') ;
            }
        });
    }

    function showForm(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#resultsArea").html("") ;
        var h = '' ;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            h = h + '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">' ;
            h = h + '<li>' ;
            h = h + '<p><strong>' + data[i].empName + '</strong></p>' ;
            h = h + '<p><strong>'  + data[i].designation +'</strong></p>' ;
            h = h + '<p><strong> Applied for ' + data[i].noOfDays + ' days of ' + data[i].category + ' leave' ;
            h = h + '<p><strong> From ' + data[i].startDate + ' To ' + data[i].endDate + '</strong></p>' ;
            h = h + '<input type="button" value="Approve" data-inline="true" onclick="approveLeave(' + data[i].id + ');" />' ;
            h = h + '<input type="button" value="Reject" data-inline="true"  onclick="rejectLeave(' + data[i].id + ');" />' ;
            h = h + '</li></ul>' ;
        }
        $("#resultsArea").html(h) ;
        $("#resultsArea").trigger("create");
    }
    function approveLeave(iID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: iID, action: "A"},
            url: '/webservices/mob_processLeave.ashx', 
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //showForm(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ;
                getLeaveDetails() ;
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown + ' ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + jqXHR.data + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                getLeaveDetails() ;
            }
        });
    }
    function rejectLeave(iID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: iID, action: "R"},
            url: '/webservices/mob_processLeave.ashx', 
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //showForm(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ;
                getLeaveDetails() ;
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown + ' ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + jqXHR.data + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                getLeaveDetails() ;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Leave Apps</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">   
    <div class="content-primary">
        <div id="resultsArea">
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working now - really, really stupid mistake - sorry to spam this most useful group.
Wrong parameter passed to mob_processLeave.ashx.  Another fitting example of writing everything down before starting to code and standardizing parameters.  Should have passed "approve" instead of "A" as the second parameter.

```
data: {id: iID, action: "approve"},
url: '/webservices/mob_processLeave.ashx',
```

Hope the code snippet helps someone, though.

Best wishes

Iyer